# How to best move fb-comments from http to https

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-comments

We are in the process of moving a Ruby On Rails website from HTTP to HTTPS.  Our sites uses the `fb-comments` plugin to capture user comments on various pages.  During our testing we found when we switch a page from HTTP to HTTPS Facebook seems to see this as a new page and no longer loads any of the previous comments for the page.

In other words, `http://my.domain.com/page1` and `https://my.domain.com/page1` are treated as separate pages with different sets of comments by `fb-comments`.

Here's a snippet of our HTML that includes the current call to `fb-comments`:

```
<div class="fb-comments"
     data-href="<%=url_for(:only_path=>false)%>"
     data-num-posts="<%=number_of_posts%>"
     data-width="<%=width%>">
</div>
```

Does any know the correct way to get Facebook to return the comments for the page regardless of the protocol (HTTP vs. HTTPS)?

Answer (score 3):

According to my testing you need to remove 'http://' and 'https://' from fb-comments, so I use this block:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="www.mydomain.com/page1.html"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep the comments afaik is to use the http URL in the data-href parameter. I don´t think there are any downsides to this.

Comment: oh, i didn´t know that the browsers would even show that for data attributes...thanx for the info!

Comment: Sorry @luschn, i think i was wrong. It doesn't show unsecure for that tag. My Bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="my.domain.com/page1" data-numposts="5" data-width="100%" colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

It is the best way to ignore your domain prefix.