# Can we get the fb comments made for the http site now that we've moved to https?

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-comments

We've just got an SSL cert and moved our pages to https. Everything was smooth except all the facebook comments have gone. The code we use to display them is

```
<?php <div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://website.com";
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "' data-numposts='5'></div> ?>
```

I've tried changing the http to https in the above (after reading this question/answer [How to best move fb-comments from http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056273/how-to-best-move-fb-comments-from-http-to-https)). It doesn't make a difference.

We have a 301 redirect from the http paths to the https.

It seems like comments made since the change are showing but is there any way to get the old ones back also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the http(s) seemed to work. Code is:

```
<div class='fb-comments' data-href='website.com";
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "' data-numposts='5'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```